# Bitwise operation in C#. How to convert 2 long's to a bool result?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

How can I check if "1" is in "9" in C#?

```
long l1 = 1L; // 0001
long l9 = 9L; // 1001
if (l1 & l9) // True (Cannot implicit convert 'long' to 'bool)
{
}
```

It's possible with "&" in JavaScript and in vb it's "And", but I just can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: You want to compare the result to 1.

Comment: C# has no implicit conversation from long/any number type to bool.

Comment: @Mafii interesting, do you have any ideas why they made it this was?

Comment: @radbyx its safer to debug and maintain code that doesnt implicitly have these conversations. Except for the fact that the bool was originally (and still is) based on integer types, there is no reason that a bool is a number. its just true or false. the c# devs made this hard decision, but I think its for the better. Its hard to understand code that has implicit number to bool conversation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// check if result of binary op is != 0
// that means "contains" 
if ((l1 & l9) != 0)
{
   ...
}
```

You need to check if the result of the operation is not equal 0.

**EDIT** 
As @Damien: correctly noted, in this case would correct to check against inequality to `0`, as simple `>0` comparison may produce false positives if 63th bit is somehow involved.

Comment: I think you should check `!=0` rather than `>0` since this will return different results if bit 63 is involved.